# Exclude multiple marked tests with pytest from command line

Tags: python, pytest

I have the following in my `pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]

markers = [
    "plot: marks SLOW plot tests (deselect with '-m \"not plot\"')",
    "open_tutorial: marks the open_tutorial (which opens VSCode all the times)"
]
```

and I have a bunch of test methods marked accordingly.

If I run

```
coverage run --branch -m pytest -m "not open_tutorial"
```

or

```
coverage run --branch -m pytest -m "not plot"
```

I got the desired results, namely the marked test are skipped, but I cannot figure out how to make `pytest` to skip both.
I tried the following

```
coverage run --branch -m pytest -m "not open_tutorial" -m "not plot"
coverage run --branch -m pytest -m "not open_tutorial" "not plot"
coverage run --branch -m pytest -m ["not open_tutorial","not plot"]
```

but none of them worked.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to pytest help:

> -m MARKEXPR           only run tests matching given mark expression.
> For example: -m 'mark1 and not mark2'.

If you want to use more than one marker you should use the `and` operator.

```
pytest -m "not open_tutorial and not plot"
```

will run all test without marks: `open_tutorial` and `plot`

but:

```
pytest -m "not open_tutorial and not plot and othermark"
```

will run tests with `othermark` if they don't have `plot` or `open_tutorial` marks.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using the `and` operator

```bash
pytest -m "not open_tutorial and not plot"
```

you can also use De Morgan's law

```bash
pytest -m "not (open_tutorial or plot)"
```